# How to use hadoop with laravel 5.2

Tags: hadoop, laravel-5

I tried to search but still there is not much examples out.
Can anyone please give me some tutorial for the laravel hadoop integration.

As in my development i want both the connections mysql and hadoop.

Comment: what do you want to do in hadoop from laravel ? could you add your usecase for hadoop ?

Comment: I want to use hadoop hive database system

Comment: Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - If you follow these guidelines, you'll have better luck getting the answer you need :)

Comment: what wrong i have asked here @JayIsTooCommon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now i got the working laravel 5.2 with hive and hadoop. I have used the below package https://packagist.org/packages/tck/odbc and made some changes to work with my laravel version.

In my development i want both the connections mysql and hadoop, so for that i have used mysql as a default connection and for hadoop i used odbc drive below is my code snippet :

```
DB::connection('odbc')->table('database_name.table_name')->select('*')->get();
```

Comment: hey, @rahul, how did you get your hadoop integration working? I am trying to get my ODBC connection to work on my Laravel 5.5 project, but I get the error message 'Invalid string or buffer length'

Comment: sadly, I decided not to use TCK/ODBC. I am using Thrift SQL to connect to Hive.